# How to design a complementary split ring resonator (CSRR)?

Tags: circuit-design, sensor, microwave, resonator

I've been looking for references that could help me to design a CSRR with no success.

Basically, given a desired resonance frenquency, I want do design/calculate a CSRR that meet the needs approximately.

I've tried:

- Google Scholar
- Stack Exchange
- Scielo
- Science direct
- IEEE

What I'm trying to say is that I googled. I googled  a lot! I also looked at the references of the articles.

The article below was the closest answer I found.

> XAVIER, George Victor Rocha et al. Design and application of a
> metamaterial superstrate on a bio-inspired antenna for partial
> discharge detection through dielectric windows. Sensors, v. 19, n. 19,
> p. 4255, 2019.

But, for split ring resonator (SRR).

In my researches I found this book. I took a fast look at it but it is not also what I'm looking for.

> CHANG, Kai. Microwave solid-state circuits and applications. New York:
> Wiley, 1994.

I would like a link, an article, a book or even a tip to shorten the path.

[image]

Comment: Checked any textbooks?

Comment: I found one, but can't get access.
https://www.amazon.com/DEVELOPMENT-COMPLEMENTARY-SPLIT-RESONATOR-ANTENNA/dp/3844328327

Comment: assuming you knew no applicable formula giving you the CSRR you want **exists** – what would you do then?

Comment: Simulation or empiricus experiments

Comment: I'd recommend starting with simulation. So, would you know how to say, simulate a CSRR of diameter D, where each ring (and gap) had fixed width W? Can you simulate it to find the resonant frequency it has? If you can write code that does "give me D, I'll give you f_resonance", then you could quite possibly just let an optimization algorithm run on it until it gives you the desired frequency.

Comment: (why I'd start with simulation: you can't let an optimizer build and empirically measure your CSRRs; and: even if you find a paper, you'd definitely want to simulate its claims, anyway)

Comment: You got a point and I agree with you. The whole ideia was to have a reference, a foundation in hands. Because, certainly, someone has the information I'm looking for, someone certainly know how to do the math

Comment: Do you recommend any simulator?

Comment: I don't think anyone actually does – they will have simulated something, but not necessarily come up with an equation that links dimensions to frequency - that might actually be very complex! Especially since these kinds of structures tend to be somewhat dependent on how close your conductor is to actually being a perfect conductor, your substrate, your production tolerances.... not much use having an analytic formula when you then simulate the same thing again to tweak it to actually work with real materials.

Comment: you can roughly approximate a sensible formula – in resonance, the lengths of the rings should both be a multiple of the wavelength – but the hard part is actually modelling wavelength in these intentionally coupled rings, it's not like you can analyze them in isolation.